# django.db.utils.OperationalError: ERROR: Endpoint ID is not specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, postgresql

I'm trying to connect my django project to a neon database, but after modifying the 'DATABASE' section in the settings.py file, I get the following error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ERROR:  Endpoint ID is not specified. Either please upgrade the postgres client library (libpq) for SNI support or pass the endpoint ID (first part of the domain name) as a parameter: '?options=project%3D<endpoint-id>'. See more at https://neon.tech/sni
```

This is how I edited the section (the commented lines are attempts to fix the problem):

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'neondb',
    'USER': myusername,
    'PASSWORD': mypassword,
    'HOST': 'myendpointid.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech',
    'OPTIONS': {
        #'service': 'my_service',
        #'sslmode': 'verify-full',
        'sslmode': 'require',
        #'project': myendpointid
        #'endpoint_id': myendpointid
    },
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

I consulted https://neon.tech/docs/connect/connectivity-issues but I'm not sure I understand what it's saying. I also tried to search online how to 'upgrade the postgres client library (libpq) for SNI support' as the error message tells me, but with no result.
Thanks in advance, hope you can help me

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i fixed it on my side:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': env("DEV_DATABASE_NAME"),
        'USER': env("DEV_DATABASE_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("DEV_DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("DEV_DATABASE_HOST"),
        'PORT': env("DEV_DATABASE_PORT"),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'require',
            'options': 'endpoint=ep-replace-this-12345679',
        },
    }
}
```

My .env file:

```
DEV_DATABASE_NAME=databasename
DEV_DATABASE_USER=aaaaaaaaa
DEV_DATABASE_PASSWORD=aaaaaaaaa
DEV_DATABASE_HOST=qwerty.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech
DEV_DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the endpoint id in the url, here you can read the docs: https://neon.tech/docs/connect/connectivity-issues#a-pass-the-endpoint-id-as-an-option

The endpoint id is your branch Id, you can get it in your dashboard.

The `NAME` option, will be: `'neondb?options=endpoint%3<endpoint-id>'`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer, but I still can't make it work. With the host being 'ep-shiny-wood-135459-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech' (host of a database I deleted), I tried  `neondb?options=endpoint%3Dep-shiny-wood-135459-pooler` and I got the same exact error. The same with and without the <> around the endpoint id, with and without "-pooler", with and without the D after %3 (which, according to that link, I assume was a typing error), with "&" in place of the "?", with "=" in place of "%3D", with and without the word "options". Did I just miss the right combination or what?

Comment: I ended up upgrading my postgresql version to 14 (which isn't that immediate) using the instructions here https://www.atlantic.net/dedicated-server-hosting/how-to-install-and-configure-postgres-14-on-ubuntu-20-04/ .